# how to stop open activity while splash screen killed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-handler, android-thread

1. I have splash screen .
2. once i open my application the splash screen will appears after completion of splash screen passed intent to HomeActivity.
3. but when i kill this app while splash screen running after some time HomeScreen will automatically open , but i want to kill the app.
4. but the HomeScreen should not show when i killed the app .

```js
public class SplashAnimation extends Activity {

    ImageView imageViewSplash;
    TextView txtAppName;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    Thread SplashThread;
    MediaPlayer mySong;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_view);


        mySong=MediaPlayer.create(SplashAnimation.this,R.raw.monn);
        mySong.start();
        imageViewSplash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewSplash);
        txtAppName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAppName);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);

        startAnimations();
    }

    private void startAnimations() {

        Animation rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
        Animation translate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);

        rotate.reset();
        translate.reset();
        relativeLayout.clearAnimation();

        imageViewSplash.startAnimation(rotate);
        txtAppName.startAnimation(translate);
        SplashThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                int waited = 0;
                while (waited < 3500) {
                    try {
                        sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    waited += 100;
                }
                SplashAnimation.this.finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashAnimation.this, LibraryView.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);
                mySong.stop();
            }
        };
        SplashThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {

        SplashAnimation.this.finish();
        finish();
        mySong.stop();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        finish();
        mySong.stop();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: try putting Intent part in runOnUiThread() method

Comment: `onDestroy()` has to be **public** since it's a callback method and part of the Activtiy lifecycle. If it's protected, it's not secure, that it can be accessed properly when needed

Comment: What is the Splash screen doing ? It plays the music right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have called `SplashThread.start()` it will do its job as long as it can do. I would recommend to use a `Handler` instead, tho you can remotely cancel the task, the Handler runs:

```
//init and declare the handler instance
private Handler delayHandler;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (delayHandler == null) {
        delayHandler = new Handler();
    }
    //your code
}

//define the task the handler should do
private void startAnimations() {
//replace the code beginning at 'Thread SplashThread = new Thread()' with the following
delayhandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashAnimation.this, LibraryView.class);
        //these flags will prevent to 'redo' the transition by hitting the back button, that also makes calling 'finish()' obsolete
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);            
        startActivity(intent);
    }
//instead of the while loop just execute the runnable after below given amount of milliseconds
}, 3500)

//to remotely cancel the runnable, if the app, respectively the Activity gets killed override 'onDestroy()'
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mySong.stop();
    //calling 'finish()' is obsolete, tho 'finish()' calls 'onDestroy()' itself
    //tell the handler to quit its job
    delayHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.Handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.monnfamily.libraryapp.UIActivity.SplashAnimation.onDestroy(SplashAnimation.java:94)

Comment: delayHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

Comment: have you defined delayHandler inside `onCreate()`?

Comment: Yes i have initialised

Comment: i just noticed, that I had a typo in my answer. Make sure it's delayHandler everywhere (and not delayhandler with small h). If this doesn't work either simply write `private Handler delayHandler = new Handler();` and leave out the definition in `onCreate()`

Answer (score 1):

Call in onStop() method

```
SplashThread.interrupt()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Timer` instead of instantiating the Thread class.

Refer the code below to start the Activity after 4 seconds. Use this in `onCreate()` of SplashActivity.

```
timer = new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
    @Override
    public void run() {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
    }
}, 4000);
```

In your `onPause()` method use:

```
timer.cancel()
```

This will terminate the timer and disregards any currently scheduled tasks.